# SQL Server 2000: Trouble with writing xml output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, sqlxml

I need to set a variable `@XMLOutput` to the value of the subquery in XMLformat.

The subquery works fine on its own, but when the whole query is run i get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near XML.

```
SELECT @XMLOutput = (SELECT loc
                       FROM ghhsitemap url
                    FOR XML AUTO, Elements)
```

A second problem: when specifying `@XMLOutput` as a variable and set its data type to `xml` it says it is not a valid data type.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: also when i add @XMLOutput as a variable and set its data type to xml it says it is not a valid data type

Comment: What's the data look like, and what do you need as a result?

Comment: It is just an integer , i want the output to say <loc>9</loc>

Comment: SQL Server 2000 **doesn't** have a XML data type... You need to upgrade to at least SQL Server 2005

Comment: Just in case: this is a good article on what is supported in terms of XML in SQL Server 2000: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163782.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported in sql 2000. And don't bother trying to return it inside a correlated subquery either - that also will not work in sql 2000. Fun eh?

In you situation, since your xml is so straightforward I'd just build the xml as a string and return it.

```
DECLARE @XmlString varchar(500)
SELECT @XmlString = '<loc>' + Cast(loc as varchar(8)) + '</loc>' FROM ghhsitemap
```

Answer (score 2):

XML datatype support wasn't included in SQL Server until SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare @XMLOutput as a varchar()

Your syntax for setting values is wrong - it should be like this:

```
SELECT @XMLOutput = loc FROM ghhsitemap url FOR XML AUTO, Elements
```

Comment: right, but i get this error:The FOR XML clause is not allowed in a ASSIGNMENT statement.